# how to catch exceptions from called functions

Tags: c++

I want to know if it is possible to catch exceptions from called functions if the called function doesn't have throw clause. The reason I am asking this question is because every time my application crashes the output statement inside catch block doesn't get printed

```
void thread11()
{
     while(true)
     {
          try
          {
              ...
              fun2() //static library function
              ...
          }
          catch(std::exception& e)
          {
              std::cout << "exception is " << e.what() << std::endl;
          }
      }
}
```

Here, because of `fun2()`, my application crashes. Is it possible to catch these exceptions by the caller function?

Comment: C functions doesn't throw C++ exceptions. And there is a difference between C++ exception and hardware and other system exceptions that can lead to crashes. In a C++ program you can only catch C++ exceptions.

Comment: I think you're asking about the syntax `catch(...)` - but I'm not sure

Comment: I think you are confusing C++ exceptions with system exceptions, which are completely different beasts. system exceptions are OS-specific, so you'll have to give us a bit more info here.

Comment: It is not possible to catch an exception which wasn't thrown, sorry. And the question in the current form is too broad.

Comment: You can't catch exceptions from a C library because it can't possibly throw exceptions.

Comment: ok, even if it is a c++ static library, Can I still catch the exception if something goes wrong in the static library function that doesn't contain throw clause

Comment: On which OS you are?

Comment: You should read the comments.

Comment: @user743414 I am using Ubuntu

Comment: *Can I still catch the exception if something goes wrong in the static library function that doesn't contain throw clause* If the called code doesn't `throw`, there's **nothing** to `catch`.

Comment: @Harry On windows exists something called SEH. Maybe there's something similar on Ubuntu? But I'm not a linux guy.

Comment: If it is a well-developed C function you *should* be able to safely use it by some combination of vetting the input and inspecting the return value. Perhaps you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: ok. can somebody tell me what I need to do take care in order to prevent my application from getting crashed in these kind of situations?

Comment: @Harry If your application (including a library inside it) does something the OS deems illegal (like accessing unmapped memory), the OS WILL shut it down, and there's not anything you can do about that generally.

Comment: Your question is '_How can I catch exceptions from something that doesn't throw exceptions_'. Do you see the problem with how you phrased that? Setting that aside, people can't help you determine how to deal with errors that you haven't described and which manifest in an unknown way, so it's too unclear to answer. If you "_feel [it] is making [your] application crash_", then explain what happens precisely, why you think it's the library, and what you did with that library before it crashed.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch all C++ exceptions using something like

```
try { fun2(); }
catch (...) { std::cout << "an unknown exception was caught\n"; }
```

`throw` clauses on functions are only restricting the set of exceptions which can escape from a function: if there is no `throw` clause, all exceptions can escape. If there a `throw` clause and a different exception is thrown, the program is `std::terminate()`ed.

When catching all exception there is no indication on what caused the exception. The only meaningful action are swallowing the error entirely or to rethrow the exception (using `throw;`) to cause it being handled elsewhere.

The description of your problem in the question implies that there actually isn't an exception (C functions cannot throw exceptions) but you rather encountered a signal: Linux, unlike some other operating systems (notably Windows) does not translate signals into exceptions. If you want to handle a signal you'll need to set up a signal handler. However, upon return from the signal handler the execution would normally just continue in the same place the program was, most likely continuing to crash. To prevent a crash from a signal handler you'd need to resolve whatever problematic condition is encountered in the signal handler. For example, memory could be mapped into an accessed location upon encountering a segmentation fault. In practice that is rarely done and in some cases it is actually impossible. Also, most signals are raise due to programming errors which are best addressed.